# create a symfony2 service

Tags: service, symfony

I am new to Symfony2 and am trying to setup my first service.  This is a curl service.
I have followed the directions on the documentation, but haven't been able to get anything to load.  I am using version 2.0.1

In my app/config/config.yml I have added:

```
parameters:
    curl_service.class:      FTW\GuildBundle\Services\Curl

services:
    curl_service:
        class:        %curl_service.class%
```

> The class file is located in src\FTW\GuildBundle\Services\Curl.php and
>   it's namespace is `namespace FTW\GuildBundle\Services;`

The class name is Curl

When I try to load my service with `$curl_service = $this->get('curl_service');` the error is get is

> You have requested a non-existent service "curl_service".

I think I am missing something very simple... any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure you clear your cache at `/app/cache/` even in development mode.

Comment: Thank you much!  Once I cleared the cache directory it started working!

Answer (score 0):

It works well on my fresh Symfony 2.0.4 install. Looks like your config is not taken into account. Are you working in dev environment?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.  I also upgraded to 2.0.4 to see if that worked.  I am using the app_dev.php environment, the other poster suggested to clear the cache and that worked.