# @doctrine.orm.entity_manager not being given to a class registered as a service

Tags: php, symfony, service, doctrine

I am trying to create a service in Symfony2 to automatically pass `Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager` to `__construct` to avoid having to pass it each time I instantiate the class, i.e.

```
// use this
$TestClass= new TestClass;

// instead of this
$entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
$TestClass= new TestClass($entityManager);
```

I created a class EntityManagerUser, tried to register it as a service and TestClass extends that.
services.yml is included, as another service works, and I've double-checked by adding (then removing) a syntax error.

I read the docs, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10427282/symfony-2-entitymanager-injection-in-service), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20587354/how-to-call-entity-manager-in-a-constructor) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7670876/create-a-symfony2-service) and I've ended up with the code below, which doesn't pass `@doctrine.orm.entity_manager`. However, the controller_listener service does receive `@templating`.

I've cleared cache via the console and manually deleted app/cache but I still see this error:

`ContextErrorException: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Test\TestBundle\ServiceUser\EntityManagerUser::__construct() must be an instance of Test\TestBundle\ServiceUser\Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager, none given, called in D:\Documents\www\Test\live\src\Test\TestBundle\Controller\MyController.php on line 84 and defined in D:\Documents\www\Test\live\src\Test\TestBundle\ServiceUser\EntityManagerUser.php line 14`

**services.yml**

```
services:
    # this one doesn't throw an error and passes @templating to __construct
    test.eventlistener.before_controller_listener:
        class: Test\TestBundle\Eventlistener\BeforeControllerListener
        arguments: [ @templating ]
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.controller, method: onKernelController }

    # the following one doesn't pass @doctrine.orm.entity_manager
    test.service_user.entity_manager_user:
        class: Test\TestBundle\ServiceUser\EntityManagerUser
        arguments: [ @doctrine.orm.entity_manager ]
```

**src/Test/TestBundle/ServiceUser/EntityManagerUser.php**

```
namespace Test\TestBundle\ServiceUser;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

class EntityManagerUser{

    protected $entityManager;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $entityManager){
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
        // N.B. it's not possible to do it this way:
        // $this->entityManager = new EntityManager;
    }

    // also tried public function __construct($entityManager){
    // and public function __construct(Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager $entityManager){

}
```

**src/Test/TestBundle/Classes/TestClass.php**

```
namespace Test\TestBundle\Classes\TestClass;

use Test\TestBundle\ServiceUser\EntityManagerUser;

class TestClass extends EntityManagerUser{
    /* currently no functions */
}
```

In my controller, line 84

```
$test= new TestClass;
// I tested that this throws the same error, it does // $test= new EntityManagerUser;
```

What have I missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked out how to do what I wanted, which was not define entityManager each time I was required in an instanciated class.

It made sense to rename EntityManagerUser to ContainerListener, a static class, and inject @service_container into it through services, so it can then also return other classes.

```
namespace Test\TestBundle\EventListener;

class ContainerListener{

    static $container;

    // knock out the parent::onKernelRequest function that we don't want
    public function onKernelRequest($event){
        return;
    }   

    public function __construct($container){
        self::$container = $container;
    }

    static function twig(){
        return self::$container->get('twig');
    }

    static function entityManager(){
        return self::$container->get('doctrine')->getEntityManager();
    }

    static function entityManagerConnection(){
        $entityManager = self::$container->get('doctrine')->getEntityManager();
        return $entityManager->getConnection();
    }

}
```

**services.yml**

```
services:
    test.event_listener.container_listener:
        class: Test\TestBundle\EventListener\ContainerListener
        arguments: [ @service_container ]
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, method: onKernelRequest }
```

**BaseClass.php** gets entityManager

```
namespace Test\TestBundle\Class;
use Test\TestBundle\EventListener\ContainerListener;

class BaseClass{
    public function __construct(){
        $this->entityManager = ContainerListener::entityManager();
    }
}
```

**TestClass.php** extends BaseClass as do others

```
class TestClass extends BaseClass(){
    function someFunction(){
        // etc etc

        // $this->entityManager exists with no construct and without passing it 
        $stmt = $this->entityManager->getConnection()->prepare( $some_sql );

        // etc etc
    }
}
```

Somewhere in **DefaultController.php**

```
# nope # $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
# nope # $TestClass= new TestClass($entityManager);

$TestClass= new TestClass; # win!
```

Answer (score 1):

Services only get their arguments if they are called through the service constructor:

```
$this->get('test.service_user.entity_manager_user');
```

Declaring the class as a service doenst make a difference if you create a new class and extend the original.

What you could do is also declare this new class as a service and still have it extend the base class.

```
test.classes.test_class:
    class: Test\TestBundle\Classes\TestClass\TestClass
    arguments: [ @doctrine.orm.entity_manager ]
```

then you dont have to define the constructor in the extended class because it is the parent.

then get the class by doing:

```
$testClass = $this->get('test.classes.test_class');
//will be instanceof Test\TestBundle\Classes\TestClass\TestClass
```

Comment: Thanks. So I can't define one service for EntityManagerUser and then just extend that class, I have to define each class as a service that I want to inject entity_manager into?

Comment: I am sorry to say but yeah, simply extending the class that is declared as a service is not enough.

Comment: Ok then it's fewer lines to do what I was trying to avoid instead. It's so tempting just to declare it as global.

Comment: It can be done, services needs an extra line `tags:
        - {name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, method: onKernelRequest}`

Comment: .. and a few other things. I posted an answer.